# Flags inside sed command file

Tags: sed

I have a sed file that replaces all occurrences of a string in a file with other string.
I want to do it inline but without using -i from terminal
What changes are to be made to the .sed file

```
#!/bin/sed 
s/include/\#include/
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it. `sed` command files can only contain commands, not options.

Comment: try (i guess) `#i` in first line of script/action list. It work for `-n` so maybe also for other option

Comment: Nope , it did not work @NeronLeVelu

Comment: To be clear your script is not replacing a string with a string, it's replacing a regexp that can contain a subset of characters (e.g. no / allowed at all and ., *, etc. are not literal and +, ? etc. can take on non-literal meaning when escaped) with a string that can contain a different subset of characters (e.g. no /, &, or \ before a digit). Be very careful with that particular house of cards!

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
{ sub(/include/,"#include"); rec = rec $0 RS }
END{ printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }
```

or if you want to operate strictly on strings:

```
BEGIN{ old="include"; new="#include" }
s = index($0,old) {$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
END{ printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }
```

which can be simplified to:

```
s = index($0,"include") {$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) "#" substr($0,s)
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
END{ printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }
```

in this particular case of just prepending `#` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work, because the `-i` and `-f` options can usually both have arguments, but you could be lucky.

The shebang line can contain one option group (aka cluster). You would need for it to contain `-f` (this is missing from your example) so the cluster could look like

```
#!/bin/sed -if
```

provided that your dialect doesn't require an argument to the `-i` option, and permits clustering like this in the first place (`-if` pro `-i -f`).

The obvious workaround is to change the script to a shell script; the `-f` option is no longer required because the script is not in a file.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sed -i 's/include/\#include/' "$@"
```